# I am trying to send image to server with RestSharp, I have tried with postman. the provided code by postman is uploading a blank image to server

Tags: c#, api, xamarin

This code uploads only blank image to server. It was successfully uploaded to server with postman. Can anybody tell which function or code postman use to upload image to server, Any help will be appreciated.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.myWeb.com/order/Update");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "9589a8e6-0c6c-6d28-05c0-900f7a9ba647");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"apiKey\"\r\n\r\na6f5c684e6a8257d0309214b80483d7f16a12bfa5e9ae2f4ace4cf0cb5f1ee8b\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Id\"\r\n\r\n3661\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachedDoc[]\"; filename=\"school_icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
//I have added this line in my code rest of the code was generated with postman.
request.AddFile("attachedDoc[]",filePath);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```